# SubSonic, and Microsoft stopping support for LINQ

Tags: linq, ado.net, subsonic

I am a front end developer working on a small social network. Currently, we are using SubSonic and it has satisfied all of our needs. Since Microsft has stopped supporting LINQ, I want to know how this will affect the development of SubSonic if at all. Is there any reason to move to ADO.net?

Comment: Microsoft stopped supporting LINQ?

Comment: LINQ is very much alive, and LINQ to SQL is still very popular and is not being dropped, as such.

Comment: Where the heck did you get that idea from?? This is - plain and simple - **NOT TRUE** - never has been. Period.

Comment: If Microsoft stops support for LINQ I'll finally learn LISP and install Linux... seriously ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft has not stopped supporting LINQ.  I think you might be referring to LINQ to SQL, which is a completely different animal.  If you're developing with SubSonic, you should have no issue with LINQ to SQL support.

Comment: And even if one does refer to Linq to SQL they have not stopped supporting it, its just that they're focusing their development efforts on Entity Framework

Answer (score 4):

LINQ is in no way going to stop being supported.

If you're referring to LINQ to SQL, you'd also be mis-informed. LINQ to SQL is indeed evident in .NET 4.0 / Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to add: Linq and Linq-to-sql and two VERY different things.

I find it so frustrating that so many people don't understand this